# CallActivityAsync same value for different functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

The variable isPlaceAvailable has always the same value as isComplete. It seems as the function monitorContext.CallActivityAsync("GetIsPlaceAvailable", input.Id) isn't even executed.

```
            while (monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime < endTime)
            {
                // Check the weather
                if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying)
                {
                    bool isComplete = await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync<bool>("SendConfirmationAlert", msg);
                    log.LogInformation($"Checking current course conditions for {input.Id} at {monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime}.");
                }

                bool isPlaceAvailable = await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync<bool>("GetIsPlaceAvailable", input.Id);

                if (isPlaceAvailable)
                {
                    // It's not raining! Or snowing. Or misting. Tell our user to take advantage of it.
                    if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying)
                    {
                        log.LogInformation($"Detected place available for {input.Id}. Notifying {input.Phone}.");
                    }

                    await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync("SendPlaceAvailableAlert", msg);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Wait for the next checkpoint
                    var interval = await monitorContext.CallActivityAsync<int>("GetInterval", null);
                    var nextCheckpoint = monitorContext.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(interval);
                    if (!monitorContext.IsReplaying) { log.LogInformation($"Next check for {input.Id} at {nextCheckpoint}."); }

                    await monitorContext.CreateTimer(nextCheckpoint, CancellationToken.None);
                }

            }

            log.LogInformation($"Monitor expiring.");
        }
```

Comment: If you add the log inside `GetIsPlaceAvailable` function then those are being logged? During debug, are the debug point being hit?

Comment: I inserted a log and breakpoint but it just skips the function GetIsPlaceAvailable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as the problem was that the first async call, which was inside the `if(!context.isReplaying) {}` caused the problem. When calling the function `SendConfirmationAlert` outside of the while loop it it works as expected.